# How to keep my program running until exit is pressed on the menu? - Library Applicatiion

Tags: java, loops

Hi I developed a library application and my 3 classes are shown below.
After I run the program and select a function eg edit a book, once edited, the program ends. Or if I select loan a book, it loans the book and then the program ends. 
What would be the best way to keep the program running - so the menu keeps appearing and the array list can be continually updated until exit is pressed while at the main menu?

I would appreciate any tips on this matter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because, in your `main()` method, you're only calling the `printMenu` method once, and only switching over the returned input once. What I would do is place the `switch` statement inside of it's own method (`parseInput`?), and then have a loop inside the `main()` method that runs while the input does not equal a certain number. For example (snippet from my suggested `main`):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int selection = printMenu(input);

while(selection != 9) {
    parseSelection(selection);
    myLibrary.showBookList();
    selection = printMent(input);
}

System.out.println("Option 9 was selected - Exit Program");
System.out.println("Exiting program...");
```